# Returning a SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have this code:

```
public static SqlDataReader GetGeneralInformation ( int RecID )
{
    using ( var conn = new SqlConnection( GetConnectionString() ) )
    using ( var cmd = conn.CreateCommand() )
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText =
        @"SELECT cs.Status, cs.Completed
          FROM NC_Steps s
          INNER JOIN NC_ClientSteps cs
              ON cs.RecID = s.RecID
          WHERE cs.ClientID = 162
          AND s.RecID = @value";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@value", RecID );
        using ( var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() )
        {
            if ( reader.Read() )
            {
                return reader;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I reference this?

I tried this but it does not work.

```
SqlDataReader reader = GeneralFunctions.GetGeneralInformation();
```

Also how would I read from the reader?

```
Reader.GetString( reader.GetOrdinal( "Status" ) )
```

**Edit**:

I am now getting the following error:

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.

Here is the updated code:

```
public static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> GetGeneralInformation ( int ClientID )
{
    using ( var conn = new SqlConnection( GetConnectionString() ) )
    using ( var cmd = conn.CreateCommand() )
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText =
        @"SELECT i.GoLiveDate, i.FirstBonusRun, i.TechFName, i.TechLName, i.TechEmail, i.TechPhone, i.WebISPFName, i.WebISPLName, 
          i.WebISPEmail, i.WebISPPhone, i.FullFillFName, i.FullFillLName, i.FullFillEmail, i.FullFillPhone, d.FName,
          d.LName, d.HomePhone, d.Email
          FROM NC_Information i
          INNER JOIN Distributor d
            ON d.DistID = i.ClientID
          WHERE clientID = @value";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@value", ClientID );
        using ( var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() )
        {
            while ( reader.Read() )
            {
                yield return reader;
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IEnumerable<IDataRecord> reader = GeneralFunctions.GetGeneralInformation( (int)Session[ "DistID" ] );

    //string result = GeneralFunctions.GetGeneralInformation( Globals.GeneralInformation ).First()[ "Status" ].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just read it like any other SqlDataReader? Does it fail? If so, that's because of your `using` statements. You're closing the connection before you get to use the reader.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I am trying to return the reader itself.  I'm not sure of the best way to accomplish what I want to do.  Basically it is an asp.net form that is populated with data from a database.  The only way I could think of doing that is to return the reader itself so i could fill the info into the asp.net textboxes.

Comment: You could return an object populated from the reader. And you still haven't said what didn't work.

Comment: @JamesWilson: I would refactor this - it's not a good design to "leak" a reader to another method (even if you can make it work), just return the results.

Comment: @BrokenGlass how would I return multiple results?  Would I have to make a separate struct?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I fixed the error, I was not using System.Data.SqlClient in the page.  Now I just need to figure out the best way to return the data.

Comment: @JamesWilson: just use a `List<T>` ?

Comment: I wouldn't use ADO.NET directly at all. I'd use Entity Framework or some other abstraction layer. I'd also do it in a separate data access layer class library. You shouldn't be doing direct data access in web pages (though I sometimes make exceptions for Data Source controls).

Comment: @BrokenGlass - not a fan of using List's for holding data from a database... they miss the whole point of using a datareader vs datatable/dataset, which is to only keep one record in RAM at a time.

Comment: Entity isn't an option or any other framework at this point.  Orders from above.

Comment: You're getting null reference exception since you're returning null. You do not need the "yield return null" part. You're misunderstanding how yield works in C#.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that leaving the function (via the return statement) kicks you out of the `using` blocks, and so the `SqlDataReader` and `SqlConnections` you are using are disposed. To get around the problem, try changing the function signature like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> GetGeneralInformation ( int RecID )
```

and then update the middle of the function like this:

```
using ( var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() )
{
    while ( reader.Read() )
    {
        yield return reader;
    }
}
```

For the final "How do I read from it?" part, it might look like this:

```
int RecID = 12345;
string result = GetGeneralInformation(RecID).First()["Status"].ToString();
```

Comment: Could you help me understand what IEnumerable<IDataRecord> and yield do?  If not I can look them up, I appreciate the answer either way.

Comment: @BrokenGlass - try it, it works great. The code is "lifted" into a separate class behind the scenes, and the dispose isn't reached until after enumeration.

Comment: @JamesWilson The yield keyword creates what is called an "Iterator". It's an object that knows how to loop over a collection of some kind. IEnumerable<IDataRecord> is another way to describe the important parts of an SqlDataReader. You can use it in a foreach(;;) loop.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn almost done implementing your suggestion to test it out.  How would I fix this line? `IEnumerable<IDataRecord> reader = GeneralFunctions.GetGeneralInformation( Globals.GeneralInformation );`

Comment: @JamesWilson what doess the compiler or exception tell you is wrong with it? It looks right to me, as long as Globals.GeneralInformation is an int.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn it was missing another using declaration on my part again.  Going to test it out now.

Comment: how do I pull out data from this?  reader. gives me a large list of options, but none seem to allow me to extrapolate a specific piece of data?  How would I pull out the Completed column?  The data returns will only ever be one row of information.

Comment: The important part of the update is .First(), which reads and returns the first row of the results.

Comment: Session[ "DistID" ] is nothing until the person logs in.  The error happens when I visit the login page.

Comment: Then you'll need a way to account for that... but now you're on a whole new question.

Comment: I fixed it.  Throwing a different error. I can ask a new question if desired.  `Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to call MetaData when reader is closed.` on this line: `launchDate.Text = GeneralFunctions.GetGeneralInformation( ( int )Session[ "DistID" ] ).First()[ "GoLiveDate" ].ToString();`

Comment: Also tried this: `launchDate.Text = reader.First()[ "GoLiveDate" ].ToString();` same error

Comment: @James: That's what i was afraid of. The reader is closed when returning from the using-statement. Initialize a custom object as shown in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4912837/284240

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn result.First() throws "No data exists for the row/column." exception. I checked result.Count() it is 1. I had to change result.First()["ColumnName" to foreach (var row in result) { row["ColumnName"].ToString(); }

Answer (score 6):

Add your connection string to AppSettings section in app.config or web.config.

```
   public string GetSqlConnection()
    {
        return  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SqlConnectionString"];
    }
```

//Function to return SqlDataReader results

```
    public SqlDataReader executeReader(string sql, SqlParameter[] parameters=null)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = GetSqlConnection();
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        if (parameters != null)
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            foreach (SqlParameter p in parameters)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        }
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        return reader;
    }
```

To use the function:

```
        string query = @"SELECT cs.Status, cs.Completed
      FROM NC_Steps s
      INNER JOIN NC_ClientSteps cs
          ON cs.RecID = s.RecID
      WHERE cs.ClientID = 162
      AND s.RecID = @value";
       //you can add more parameters by adding commas
       var parameters = new SqlParameter[] {
            new SqlParameter("@value", RecID )
           };

        SqlDataReader dr = executeReader(query, parameters);
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            //fill your controls with data 
        }
        dr.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32264644/543814) deserves mentioning. A very simple and pleasant-to-use solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are creating the database connection **within** your method.

If you are going to **share** database resources between many methods, move `SqlConnection` outside this scope.

This way you can return the Reader from this function and it will persist.

Also, don't `.Read()` within this function, just return the object.