# Return datareader from method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following method

```
    public static SqlDataReader MenuDataReader(string url)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spR_GetChildMenus", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageUrl", url);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MenuId", ParameterDirection.Output);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParentId", ParameterDirection.Output);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TitleText", ParameterDirection.Output);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExternalUrl", ParameterDirection.Output);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullUrl", ParameterDirection.Output);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChildCount", ParameterDirection.Output);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    //return reader;

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        return reader;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

which im calling like this

```
        SqlDataReader reader = MenuDataReader(url);
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            { }}
```

however im getting the error message

> Invalid attempt to call HasRows when reader is closed.

can anyone help me out

thanks

Comment: Are you sure its not returning Null?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252531/returning-a-sqldatareader

Comment: why you want return reader?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do you really need the reader, or do you just need some way to iterate over the rows inside it? I suggest an *iterator block*. You can iterate over your rows inside the source method, and `yield` each row in turn to the caller.

There is a twist with this technique: because you're yielding the *same* object with each iteration, there are cases where this can cause a problem, and so you're best off also asking for a delegate to copy the contents of the row somewhere. I also like to abstract this to a generic method that can be used for any query, and use the same delegate technique to handle parameter data, like so:

```
private IEnumerable<T> GetRows<T>(string sql, Action<SqlParameterCollection> addParameters, Func<IDataRecord, T> copyRow)
{
     using (var cn = new SqlConnection("Connection string here"))
     using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn)
     {
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         addParameters(cmd.Parameters);
         cn.Open();
         using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
         {
             while (rdr.Read())
             {
                 yield return copyRow(rdr);
             }
             rdr.Close();
         }
     }
}

public IEnumerable<MenuItem> GetChildMenus(string url)
{
     return GetRows<MenuItem>("spR_GetChildMenus", p =>
     {
         //these lines are copied from your question, but they're almost certainly wrong
         p.AddWithValue("@PageUrl", url);
         p.AddWithValue("@MenuId", ParameterDirection.Output);
         p.AddWithValue("@ParentId", ParameterDirection.Output);
         p.AddWithValue("@TitleText", ParameterDirection.Output);
         p.AddWithValue("@ExternalUrl", ParameterDirection.Output);
         p.AddWithValue("@FullUrl", ParameterDirection.Output);
         p.AddWithValue("@ChildCount", ParameterDirection.Output);
     }, r =>
     {
         return new MenuItem( ... );
     }
 }
```

Comment: One corner case where you really _do_ want to return a reader is when doing bulk inserts into a separate database which has its own connection.

Answer (score 24):

As seen in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx :

```
  public static SqlDataReader ExecuteReader(String connectionString, String commandText,
      CommandType commandType, params SqlParameter[] parameters) {
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn)) {
        cmd.CommandType = commandType;
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

        conn.Open();
        // When using CommandBehavior.CloseConnection, the connection will be closed when the 
        // IDataReader is closed.
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        return reader;
     }
  }
```

Comment: This is my favourite solution by far

Comment: This is a *very* good answer. You could go even further and make everything `IDataReader`, `IDbCommand`, `IDbConnection`, and `DbParameter`, removing the Sql dependency. Instead of a connection string, you would pass `Func<IDbConnection> dbConnectionFactory`, a function that creates the desired connection.

Comment: Do you then need to make sure that you implement a using statement around the returned reader to ensure it's properly closed?

Comment: Does the connection stay open?

Comment: @TylerNielsen - the example from the link shows the returned reader wrapped in a using statement. Look at the GetDepartments() function

Comment: @timo any example code for a learner?

Comment: @Smith I have posted a new [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69709488/543814) demonstrating my suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

I would not return the reader - the `Dispose` of your connection and command are closing the connection. I would instead return a representative model of your data.

Comment: any clues on how to do that?

Comment: You *can* return the reader from your function, but only if you pass a connection object *into* it as a parameter. You can create reader with "CommandBehavior.CloseConnection" option so the will be closed automatically when reader closes. Had to find this a hard way: http://codecorner.galanter.net/2013/08/30/solution-for-sqldatareader-readcolumnheader-nullreferenceexception/

Comment: when you are in `while (reader.Read())` construct your objects and then return a `List<>`

Comment: @Ric that kind of defeats the purpose of using a datareader. You're not much better than Fill()-ing a dataset at this point. There are ways to do this that preserve the one-record-in-memory-at-a-time nature of the DataReader.

Comment: absolutely, but disposing of your connection then your command leads to doing something other than returning your reader. that's what i got from this answer and is what i would do instead, return strongly typed objects etc

Answer (score 1):

When you return inside the `using` statement the code calls `Dispose` on the `SqlConnection`. This closes the `DataReader`, causing the error.

Comment: i ve modified to "abbas" way and i get the error Invalid attempt to call HasRows when reader is closed. so I think I need to change it

Comment: @andrewslaughter the Reader is dependent on the SqlConnection. When you exit the using statement, the SqlConnection gets closed and you can't use the Reader after that. I would go with the suggestion by Daniel A White to read from your reader before exiting the method. Or pass a SqlConnection into the method so it doesn't get closed as suggested by Yuriy Galanter .

Answer (score 1):

Triggered by a question under [Danan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32264644/543814), here is a solution based on abstractions. Additionally, it uses good practices like [using declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using#using-declaration), async programming (with cancellation tokens omitted for brevity), and proper object disposal (especially with regards to the connection).

```cs
// Example invocation
public async Task DemonstrateUsage()
{
    var query = @"SELECT * FROM Order WHERE Id = @Id;";

    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        ["@Id"] = 1,
    };

    // Caller disposes the reader, which disposes the connection too
    await using var reader = await this.ExecuteReader(this.CreateConnection, query, parameters);

    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
        Console.Log("And another row!");
}

// Concrete implementation of how we produce connections
private DbConnection CreateConnection()
{
    return new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");
}

// Fully abstract solution
private async Task<DbDataReader> ExecuteReader(Func<DbConnection> connectionFactory,
    string query, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> parameters,
    CommandType commandType = CommandType.Text)
{
    var connection = connectionFactory();

    try
    {
        await using var command = connection.CreateCommand();

        command.CommandType = commandType;
        command.CommandText = query;
        foreach (var pair in parameters)
        {
            var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
            parameter.ParameterName = pair.Key;
            parameter.Value = pair.Value;
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        }

        await connection.OpenAsync();
        return await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    }
    catch
    {
        // We have failed to return a disposable reader that can close the connection
        // We must clean up by ourselves
        await connection.DisposeAsync();

        throw;
    }
}
```