# Can I close a SqlDataReader after DataBind()

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, data-binding, dispose

Say I do something like this

```
using (SqlDataReader allUsersDataSource = AdminDB.GetUsers())
{
    // bind all portal users to dropdownlist
    allUsers.DataSource = allUsersDataSource;
    allUsers.DataBind();
}
```

Will the dataBinded still behave correctly or does it need the `SqlDataReader` to be undisposed?

EDIT: Additional Information

```
public static SqlDataReader GetUsers() 
{
    // Create Instance of Connection and Command Object
    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection( (string) PortalSettings.GetPortalSetting("ConnectionString")))
    using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetUsers", myConnection))
    {

        // Mark the Command as a SPROC
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // Open the database connection and execute the command
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        // Return the datareader
        return dr;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252531/returning-a-sqldatareader

Comment: @Habib very cool thank you. Didn't realise that was even possible

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using to bind the data uses **using** block

```
using (SqlDataReader allUsersDataSource = AdminDB.GetUsers())
   {
    // bind all portal users to dropdownlist
     allUsers.DataSource = allUsersDataSource;
     allUsers.DataBind();
   }
```

using takes only IDisposable objects and calls the Dispose method when the block execution ends. So you need not to worry about Disposing the Reader object here.

Comment: I'm aware I am closing the DataReader. But does the DataBind need to have the SqlDataReader still 'alive' to work or does the databind save the information and no longer needs the datareader?