# DataReader is not fetching the values from MySqlDatabase

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have a datagridview that holds the bio_id and email. I am iterating through the datagridview to get the time records of the employee based on the bio_id and dates. If I create a MySql syntax in the MySql itself, it gets the right value but when I use the MySqlDataReader, it gives me a null value. Below are the codes:

```
public MySqlDataReader SendTimeLogs(string fromDate, string toDate, int bioId)
        {
            using (var cn = new DatabaseConnection().ConnectToMySql())
            {
                const string query = @"SELECT MIN(scan_time) as 'Time In', MAX(scan_time) as 'Time Out', 
                TIMEDIFF(MAX(scan_time),MIN(scan_time)) as difference 
                FROM `filtered_dates` 
                WHERE bio_id = @bioId AND date BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate GROUP BY date ORDER BY date asc";
                var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cn);
                cn.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromDate", fromDate);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@toDate", toDate);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bioId", bioId);
                return cmd.ExecuteReader();       
            }
        }

private void SendEmail()
        {

            var rdr = new EmployeeDataAccess().GetBioIdEmail();
            while (rdr.HasRows && rdr.Read())
            {
                dgvBioIdList.Rows.Add(rdr["bio_id"].ToString(), rdr["email_add"].ToString());
            }


            for (var i = 0; i < dgvBioIdList.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                var message = "Time Logs for Bio ID: " +dgvBioIdList.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
                var x = new FilteredDatesDataAccess();
                var timeLogs = x.SendTimeLogs(dtpStart.Text, dtpStop.Text,
                    Convert.ToInt32(dgvBioIdList.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value));
                var rec = dgvBioIdList.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

                Console.WriteLine(message);
                Console.WriteLine(rec);
                while (timeLogs.HasRows && timeLogs.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(timeLogs["Time In"] + @" - " + timeLogs["Time Out"]);
                }
            }
        }
```

I get the Console.WriteLine(message); and Console.WriteLine(rec); just fine but my while loop is not being written in the console. Can you help? Thank you.

Comment: What's the date format string used for fromDate and toDate?

Comment: It's "yyyy-MM-dd". I think the issue occurs when I close the connection.

Comment: well step thru your code. You have the best built-in debugger in VS

Comment: Try refactoring SendTimeLogs into IEnumerable, or just copy the whole data into array http://stackoverflow.com/a/10252597/529282