# How to read values from stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, .net-core, sqldatareader

I'm trying to read values from stored procedures on my .NET Core Web API.

Here is what is get as an response:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_FieldCount()
   at System.Data.Common.DbEnumerator.BuildSchemaInfo()
   at System.Data.Common.DbEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.HandleEnumerable(JsonClassInfo elementClassInfo, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonWriter writer, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Int32 originalWriterDepth, Int32 flushThreshold, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteAsyncCore(Stream utf8Json, Object value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
```

Here is my code:

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myConnString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetUsers", con)) // Simple proc which returning all 'child' users
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@parentUserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = parentUserId;

            // open connection to database
            con.Open();

            //set the SqlCommand type to stored procedure and execute
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

           message.Data = reader;
        }
    }
    return message;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    message.IsValid = false;
}
```

When I debugged this I realized that data exist in result but its nested in another objects like it looks on image here:

[image]

Comment: When the code exits from the using block that contains the connection both the connection and its associated reader will be closed.

Comment: You need to hold the connection and the reader alive (i.e., not disposed) until you are finished reading from the reader.  DataReaders and using statements aren't always a good match.

Comment: @Steve Thanks for great explanation! How could I avoid that, could you help me a little bit please Steve. Thanks!

Comment: Usually a DataReader is not passed out from the method where it has been created. I usually avoid it (the datareader) and replace it with a good ORM like Dapper that transforms automatically my queries in a List of objects defined in my model. This should be the solution to your problem in my opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving `return message;` inside of the two `using` statements.

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myConnString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetUsers", con)) // Simple proc which returning all 'child' users
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@parentUserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = parentUserId;

            // open connection to database
            con.Open();

            //set the SqlCommand type to stored procedure and execute
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

           while (reader.Read())
            {
                // add each line to message.Data
            }

           return message;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    message.IsValid = false;
}
```

As soon as you leave the `using`, your `reader` is lost.

How you handle this `// add each line to message.Data` will depend on what `message.Data` looks like, which we can't tell.

Also, a couple of other things:

`cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;` -- You have this twice. Not hurting anything, but not helping either.

You should really look into a more elegant way to do your data access. Straight ADO.NET is clunky and hard to work with. Explore options like Entity Framework, and Dapper.

Comment: Moving the return inside the using statements will change nothing. The reader will be closed even if you _return_ inside the using

Comment: Ah shoot. @Steve is right. It's been too long since I've worked with ADO. I edited my answer. But also, check out the documents on Reader: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Answer (score 2):

When the code exits from the using block that contains the connection both the connection and its associated reader will be closed.
This means that a DataReader is usually not well suited to be passed around between methods. Some workaround exists, [see here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252531/returning-a-sqldatareader) but I have found more useful to totally abandon the SqlDataReader and SqlCommand and replacing them with a simple ORM like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)

Now, suppose that you have a User class with some properties like these that matches exactly the names of the datatable fields.

```
public class User
{
     public Guid ID {get;set;}
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public string EMail {get;set;}
     public Guid ParentID {get;set;}
     ... etc ...
}
```

At this point your code, using Dapper would be

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myConnString))
{
    con.Open();
    List<User> users = con.Query<User>("GetUsers",  
                       new {parentUserId=parentUserId}, 
                       commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
    message.Data = users;
    return message;
}
```

Of course the field Data in the message class should be of type User, or if you use for many different types you can even serialize the list as Json string and return

Comment: I've used dapper for a long time, it's a solid choice, but also consider RepoDB which allows for similar things + has a few more toys to make life easier.  https://repodb.net/

Comment: It seems a very good option. I will keep it on my radar, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will be happier using something like ***Dapper***, but, if you want to follow the straight SqlConnection/DataReader path, consider something like this simple wrapper class:

```
public class WrappedReader : IDisposable
{
    public SqlDataReader Reader { get; }
    public SqlConnection Connection { get; }
    public WrappedReader(SqlConnection connection, SqlDataReader reader)
    {
        Reader = reader;
        Connection = connection;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Reader?.Dispose();
        Connection?.Dispose();
    }
```

Instead of returning a DataReader, you construct a `WrappedReader` and return it, something like:

```
public static WrappedReader TestWrappedReader()
{
    var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("Select * from SomeTable", connection))
    {
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        return new WrappedReader(connection, reader);
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
 using (var wrappedReader = TestWrappedReader())
 {
     var reader = wrappedReader.Reader;
     if (reader.HasRows)
     {
         while (reader.Read())
         {
             DoSomethingWith(reader);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Good idea, but I have the feeling the OP is trying to pass the datareader through a webapi to client code. _(.... on my .NET Core Web API.)_ If this is the context then wrapping the reader doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Yeah, I agree.  It's an idea.  It's definitely not the way to go for many situations.  But it is a lightweight solution when you are wed to the idea of DataReaders (which does happen sometimes). My most recent use of something like this was for creating JSON files from table names (no types, just table names).  You create a reader for a SELECT * statement for the table, get the metadata from the reader, build a `Dictionary<string, object>` where each object represents a row, and then JSON serialize the dictionary.