# Please help me understand how to convert my code to work like this thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm not sure if I need to create a whole new class or what, I am very new to asp.net.

Here is my code:

```
public static IEnumerable<DistInfo> GetGeneralInformation ( int ClientID )
{
    using ( var conn = new SqlConnection( GetConnectionString() ) )
    using ( var cmd = conn.CreateCommand() )
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText =
        @"SELECT i.GoLiveDate, i.FirstBonusRun, i.TechFName, i.TechLName, i.TechEmail, i.TechPhone, i.WebISPFName, i.WebISPLName, 
          i.WebISPEmail, i.WebISPPhone, i.FullFillFName, i.FullFillLName, i.FullFillEmail, i.FullFillPhone, d.FName,
          d.LName, d.HomePhone, d.Email
          FROM NC_Information i
          INNER JOIN Distributor d
            ON d.DistID = i.ClientID
          WHERE clientID = @value";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@value", ClientID );
        using ( var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() )
        {
            while ( reader.Read() )
            {
                var distInfo = new DistInfo
                {
                    AnticipatedLaunchDate = reader.GetDateTime( reader.GetOrdinal( "GoLiveDate" ) )
                };
                yield return distInfo;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

gives the are you missing an assemblyt or reference.  Does this mean i need to create a DistInfo class to make this work?

new DistInfo gives the same error as above.

Sorry I am very new to asp.net and don't quite understand how to make mine work like in this post:

[I keep getting this error: "Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912782/i-keep-getting-this-error-invalid-attempt-to-call-read-when-reader-is-closed/4912837#4912837)

Comment: Did you define the `DistInfo` class?

Comment: You don't understand basic programming principles and you're trying to connect to the database? Really? Rewind and start over. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436(v=vs.71).aspx From Hello World.

Comment: @walther I already have the site connecting to the database, handling sessions, logging in users.  Connecting to the databse isn't even the problem.  Pulling information from the database isn't even the problem.  However in THIS instance pulling this much information from a database and then trying to throw that into text boxes is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you actually have a class called `DistInfo`? Does the code compile? If not, you'll need to add a new DistInfo class that has at least a `DateTime`. Something like:

```
public class DistInfo
{
    public DateTime AnticipatedLaunchDate { get; set; }
}
```

You can add more properties in there if you need to :)

Comment: Alright I now have this.  How do I make this work now? `IEnumerable<DistInfo> distInfo = GeneralFunctions.GetGeneralInformation( ( int )Session[ "DistID" ] );
            launchDate.Text = distInfo.AnticipatedLaunchDate;` It doesn't like the AnticipatedLaunchDate.

Comment: You'll need to change the second part to be `launchDate.Text = distInfo.AnticipatedLaunchDate.ToShortDateString();`

Comment: distInfo doesn't like .AnticipatedLaunchDate.  It gives the following error: system.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<DistInfo> does not contain a definition for 'AnticipatedLaunchDate' and no extension method 'AnticipatedLaunchDate' accepting a first argument of type....

Comment: Ah sorry, you have a list of the items there, not just one, that's what IEnumerable<DistInfo> means, a LIST of DistInfo. What exactly are you trying to get the launchDate control to say?

Comment: the launchDate control should be populated with the result from the GetGeneralInformation( int ClientID ) method.  Which will either be a DateTime or empty.

Comment: Should that method only return one DistInfo? If so, change the GetGeneralInformation to return just a `DistInfo`, then in the `while` loop change the `yield return` to just `return`

Answer (score 2):

If you need only to return a date/time info then define your method like this

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetGeneralInformation(int ClientID)
```

And simplify your reading loop like this

```
int goLiveDateOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("GoLiveDate");
while (reader.Read()) {
    yield return reader.GetDateTime(goLiveDateOrdinal);
}
```

You need to create a class only if you have to return more than one value.

Comment: The datetime is just one property, I will eventually have around 16.  Was just using one to get it to work. =(  I did get past the error however, it was related to the session variable.  Now onto the next error. :)