# C# How do I take my sqlDataReader offline?

Tags: c#, database, memory-leaks, sqldatareader

**I have a memory leak**, due to not closing the connection properly. This is due to using a global function to access the database (with different sql strings), but I pass back an sqldatareader. **I cant close this in the method, nor the connection to the DB, as it closes access to the data!** And it doesnt close properly from outside this method. :(

**Is there Anyway way I can take the desired table, that the sqldatareader grants access to, offline.** So that I can close all the connections, but still access the table.

Note, Different tables are returned so different fields exist. I dont want to have to duplicate code each time I try and connect.

```
private SqlDataReader OpenDataStream(String sql)
{
    SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand();
    sqlComm.Connection = new SqlConnection();
    sqlComm.Connection.ConnectionString = @"Myconnectionstring";
    sqlComm.CommandText = sql;
    sqlComm.Connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader data = null;
    data = sqlComm.ExecuteReader();

    return data;

    // Closing data here, or connection, results in returned object inaccessable.
}
```

or maybe a valid working way of closing it all down outside the method (after I have accessed what I need)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return DataReader from DataLayer in Using statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850065/return-datareader-from-datalayer-in-using-statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [DataTable.Load Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.load.aspx) method:

```
private DataTable OpenDataStream(String sql)
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand();
    sqlComm.Connection = new SqlConnection();
    sqlComm.Connection.ConnectionString = @"Myconnectionstring";
    sqlComm.CommandText = sql;
    sqlComm.Connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader data = null;
    data = sqlComm.ExecuteReader();

    dt.Load(data);

    data.Close();

    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to close connection, using(var sqlComm.Connection.ConnectionString = @"Myconnectionstring"){} is preferred way

Answer (score 3):

You could just return a `DataTable` instead of a `SqlDataReader`. This will fill the table with your data and you can close the connections before the method ends its execution.

```
private DataTable GetDataTable(String sql)
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    return ds.Tables[0];
}
```

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx) might be worth a read.

Answer (score 2):

Don't return the reader, return a populated `DataTable` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using using something like a `DataSet` that provides off-line access to your data. Some examples here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971499.aspx

or

This question provides a number of methods for taking the data out of a datareader and storing it in memory - [How can I easily convert DataReader to List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464883/how-can-i-easily-convert-datareader-to-listt)