# while on IDataReader.Read doesn't work with yield return but foreach on reader does

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, sqlite, datareader

This is a commonly seen ADO.NET pattern to retrieve data from database using a data reader, but strangely doesn't work.

**Doesn't work:**

```
public static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> SelectDataRecord<T>(string query, string connString)
                                                          where T : IDbConnection, new()
{
    using (var conn = new T())
    {
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.Connection.ConnectionString = connString;

            cmd.Connection.Open();
            using (var reader = (DbDataReader)cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // the main part
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    yield return (IDataRecord)reader;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**This does work:**

```
public static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> SelectDataRecord<T>(string query, string connString)
                                                          where T : IDbConnection, new()
{
    using (var conn = new T())
    {
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.Connection.ConnectionString = connString;

            cmd.Connection.Open();
            using (var reader = (DbDataReader)cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // the main part
                foreach (var item in reader.Cast<IDataRecord>())
                {
                    yield return item;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The only relevant change I see is that in the first code the iterator is returned from `while` loop while in the second it is returned from a `foreach` loop.

I call it like:

```
// I have to buffer for some reason
var result = SelectDataRecord<SQLiteConnection>(query, connString).ToList(); 

foreach(var item in result)
{
    item.GetValue(0); // explosion
}
```

I tried with [SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/) .NET connector as well as [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) connector. The result is the same, i.e. first approach fails, second one succeeds.

**Exception**

*SQLite*

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll. Additional information: **No current row**

*MySQL*

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in MySql.Data.dll. Additional information: **No current query in data reader**

Is it because of the implementation differences between `reader.Read` and `reader.GetEnumerator` in the specific ADO.NET connectors? I couldn't see any noticeable difference when I checked the source of `System.Data.SQLite` project, `GetEnumerator` calls `Read` internally. I am assuming ideally in both cases the `yield` keyword prevents eager execution of the method and the loops have to be executed only once the enumerator is enumerated externally.

---

**Update:**

I use this pattern to be on the safe side (essentially the same as the second approach but a little less verbose),

```
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    foreach (IDataRecord record in reader as IEnumerable)
        yield return record;
```

Comment: This method will force you to write code that is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. You should add a mechanism to accept query parameter data separate from the sql string.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn oh yes, what I presented here is a less fleshed out version. Sure I handle that via parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the two examples is because `foreach` has different semantics from `while` which is a plain loop. The underlying `GetEnumerator` of `foreach` makes the difference here.

As Joel says, **in the first example**, the same reader object is yielded on each iteration of the `while` loop. This is because the both the `IDataReader` as well as `IDataRecord` are the same here, which is unfortunate. When a `ToList` is called on the resulting sequence, the yielding is complete upon which the `using` blocks closes the reader and connection objects, and you end up with a list of disposed reader objects of the same reference.

**In the second example**, the `foreach` on data reader ensures *a copy* of `IDataRecord` is yielded. The `GetEnumerator` is implemented like this:

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    return new DbEnumerator(this); // the same in MySQL as well as SQLite ADO.NET connectors
}
```

where `MoveNext` of `System.Data.Common.DbEnumerator` class is implemented like:

```
IDataRecord _current;

public bool MoveNext() // only the essentials
{
    if (!this._reader.Read())
        return false;

    object[] objArray = new object[_schemaInfo.Length];
    this._reader.GetValues(objArray); // caching into obj array
    this._current = new DataRecordInternal(_schemaInfo, objArray); // a new copy made here
    return true;
}
```

The `DataRecordInternal` is the actual implementation of the `IDataRecord` which is yielded from the `foreach` which is not the same reference as the reader, but a cached copy of all the values of the row/record.

The `System.Linq.Cast` in this case is a mere representation preserving cast which does nothing to the overall effect. `Cast<T>` will be implemented like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Cast<T>(this IEnumerable source)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
        yield return (T)item; // representation preserving since IDataReader implements IDataRecord
}
```

An example without `Cast<T>` call can be shown to not exhibit this problem.

```
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    foreach (var record in reader as IEnumerable)
        yield return record;
```

The above example just works fine.

---

An important distinction to make is that **the first example** is problematic only if you are not making use of the values read from database in its first enumeration itself. It is only the subsequent enumerations which throw since reader will be disposed by then. An eg,

```
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    while (reader.Read())
        yield return reader;

...
foreach(var item in ReaderMethod())
{
    item.GetValue(0); // runs fine
} 

...
foreach(var item in ReaderMethod().ToList())
{
    item.GetValue(0); // explosion
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not `while` vs `foreach` that makes the difference. It's the call to `.Cast<T>()`.

In the first sample, you are yielding on the *same* object in each iteration of the while loop. If you're not careful, you end up having completed the yield iterator before actually using the data, and the DataReader will already be disposed. This can happen if you were to, say, call `.ToList()` after calling this method. The best you could hope for there would be for every record in the list to have the same value.
<sub>*(Pro tip: most of the time you don't want to call `.ToList()` until you absolutely have to. It's better to just work with IEnumerable records).*</sub>

In the second sample, when you call `.Cast<T>()` on the datareader, you are effectively making a copy of the data as it iterates through each record. Now you are no longer yielding the same object.

Comment: To make it clear, as you have acknowledged in comments in the linked question, I could yield return the same reader object in a while loop and then read values from it externally directly in a `Select` or `foreach`. If I read it after first `ToList()` then the exception. This is not a problem in the `Cast<T>` example since, as you say, a different object is returned from the enumerator. I personally think it was a very poor choice from MS to let `IDataReader` class implement `IDataRecord` making no difference between the enumerable and the enumerator.

Comment: A small correction: It is not the `Cast<T>` call that makes the difference, it is the `foreach`. Specifically the `IEnumerator` of `foreach`. I fired up a reflector and saw the source. The `GetEnumerator` method returns `DbEnumerator` which caches the values of the record into separate object. `Cast<T>` is merely doing a cast which is not identity changing. The reader object will be still be the same after all the casts. I have updated my code with a working pattern which uses no `Cast<T>` call, just plain `foreach`.