# How to "zip" or "rotate" a variable number of lists?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

If I have a list containing an arbitrary number of lists, like so:

```
var myList = new List<List<string>>()
{
    new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d" },
    new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4" },
    new List<string>() { "w", "x", "y", "z" },
    // ...etc...
};
```

...is there any way to somehow "zip" or "rotate" the lists into something like this?

```
{ 
    { "a", "1", "w", ... },
    { "b", "2", "x", ... },
    { "c", "3", "y", ... },
    { "d", "4", "z", ... }
}
```

The obvious solution would be to do something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Rotate<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Min(x => x.Count()); i++)
    {
        yield return list.Select(x => x.ElementAt(i));
    }
}

// snip

var newList = myList.Rotate();
```

...but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way of doing so, using linq or otherwise?

Comment: Why do you want to solve it specifically using LINQ?

Comment: @Moo-Juice -- good point, I edited my title. I think I just automatically assumed that the solution would use linq in some way, but I suppose that's not necessarily the case.

Comment: Your example code is very inefficient if the sequences are not random access.

Comment: I gave a general answer to another question which was more restricted which utilizes LINQ [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5039863/390278) and is a more direct answer to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Items from 3 collections using Linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284315/create-items-from-3-collections-using-linq)

Comment: @ensisNoctis -- not quite. That post contains answers that can handle only exactly three collections, this post is asking for code that can handle an arbitrary number of collections.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can roll your own ZipMany instance which manually iterates each of the enumerations. This will likely perform better on larger sequences than those using `GroupBy` after projecting each sequence:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> ZipMany<TSource, TResult>(
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> source,
    Func<IEnumerable<TSource>, TResult> selector)
{
   // ToList is necessary to avoid deferred execution
   var enumerators = source.Select(seq => seq.GetEnumerator()).ToList();
   try
   {
     while (true)
     {
       foreach (var e in enumerators)
       {
           bool b = e.MoveNext();
           if (!b) yield break;
       }
       // Again, ToList (or ToArray) is necessary to avoid deferred execution
       yield return selector(enumerators.Select(e => e.Current).ToList());
     }
   }
   finally
   {
       foreach (var e in enumerators) 
         e.Dispose();
   }
}
```

Comment: That must have taken ages to type on a phone... :)

Comment: I went and cleaned it up for ya. I believe it captures your intent.

Comment: @JeffMercado Your beat me to it by literally 5 seconds. I had pretty much the same code (which I tested and it worked). I think it's a good edit.

Comment: @JeffMercado: didn't realize you'd done it too...oh well we all did the same thing. @Eric, I added comments detailing why `ToList` (or `ToArray`) would be important.

Comment: Would the enumerators be disposed of when this method hits the yield break?  The question stems from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47521/using-yield-to-iterate-over-a-datareader-might-not-close-the-connection/47799#47799

Comment: @Oliver: this is a question-and-answer site. Post a question if you have a question!

Comment: @EricLippert Noted!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337340/enumerator-disposal-when-not-using-using-or-manually-calling-dispose

Comment: This method would leave un-disposed enumerators.

Comment: @Oliver: Ah, now I understand the thrust of your question. You are absolutely right; I neglected to dispose the enumerators. I'll fix it.

Comment: Note here that I am making some assumptions in the fix. For example, if an exception happens while selecting out the `GetEnumerator()` calls, enumerators that have already been created are not disposed. If a `Dispose()` throws an exception then the remaining enumerators are not disposed. Enumerators are presumed to be non null. And so on. If these conditions are violated then the program has a more serious bug in it already than a few leaked resources!

Comment: One improvement I made to this: if enumerators is empty there should be a yield break;

Comment: Otherwise you are invoking the selector to return a `TResult` from an empty `IEnumerable<TSource>` which is not always possible (e.g. if `TResult` is not an `IEnumerable`)

Answer (score 12):

You can do this by using the `Select` extension taking a `Func<T, int, TOut>`:

```
var rotatedList = myList.Select(inner => inner.Select((s, i) => new {s, i}))
                        .SelectMany(a => a)
                        .GroupBy(a => a.i, a => a.s)
                        .Select(a => a.ToList()).ToList();
```

This will give you another `List<List<string>>`.

**Breakdown**

```
.Select(inner => inner.Select((s, i) => new {s, i}))
```

For each inner list, we project the list's content to a new anonymous object with two properties: `s`, the string value, and `i` the index of that value in the original list.

```
.SelectMany(a => a)
```

We flatten the result to a single list

```
.GroupBy(a => a.i, a => a.s)
```

We group by the `i` property of our anonymous object (recall this is the index) and select the `s` property as our values (the string only).

```
.Select(a => a.ToList()).ToList();
```

For each groups, we changed the enumerable to a list and another list for all the groups.

Comment: +1, but I may be in the minority here in thinking the OPs original method was *way* more readable.

Comment: I'm in that boat too, but still impressed

Comment: @Moo-Juice I agree. And it yield better performance. I see this as an edge case where LINQ works, but is far from optimal.

Comment: +1 great answer. Even if it's just for the sake of the answer, as opposed to efficiency, it's a nice solution.

Comment: Your keys will be first seen order [in the grouping source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501.aspx), but elements inside each grouping shall be returned/yielded based on when they appear in their source.

Comment: @user7116 Thank's. I never was sure. I'll change my answer to put an ordering.

Comment: @SimonBelanger: I revised my comment, assuming you have a sorted order of keys, they IGrouping's will come back in that order.

Comment: @user7116 So it this case, it does preserve ordering. Good to know.

Answer (score 5):

How about using `SelectMany` and `GroupBy` with some indexes?

```
// 1. Project inner lists to a single list (SelectMany)
// 2. Use "GroupBy" to aggregate the item's based on order in the lists
// 3. Strip away any ordering key in the final answer
var query = myList.SelectMany(
    xl => xl.Select((vv,ii) => new { Idx = ii, Value = vv }))
       .GroupBy(xx => xx.Idx)
       .OrderBy(gg => gg.Key)
       .Select(gg => gg.Select(xx => xx.Value));
```

From LinqPad:

[image: we groupa da items]

Comment: +1. This is actually more in line with the method's signature used in the question (`IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`).

Answer (score 3):

Here's an inefficient variant based on Matrix Transposition:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Rotate<T>(
        this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> src)
    {
        var matrix = src.Select(subset => subset.ToArray()).ToArray();
        var height = matrix.Length;
        var width = matrix.Max(arr => arr.Length);

        T[][] transpose = Enumerable
            .Range(0, width)
            .Select(_ => new T[height]).ToArray();
        for(int i=0; i<height; i++)
        {        
            for(int j=0; j<width; j++)
            {            
                transpose[j][i] = matrix[i][j];            
            }
        }

        return transpose;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Moo-Juice Not horribly efficient, although it could be improved. Lots of to-arraying going on. :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [linqlib project on codeplex](http://linqlib.codeplex.com/), it has a rotate function that does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can condense `for` loops using [Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx):

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, myList.Min(l => l.Count))
    .Select(i => myList.Select(l => l[i]).ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(from count in Range(myList[0].Count)
select new List<string>(
    from count2 in Range(myList.Count)
    select myList[count2][count])
    ).ToList();
```

It ain't pretty, but I think it'll work.

Comment: I think this solution works only if there are three lists inside `mylist`. I was hoping more for a solution which works no matter how many lists there are.

Comment: Okay, I *think* my edit makes that happen. Not 100% sure, but the basic idea is there.