# Enumerator disposal when not using using, foreach or manually calling Dispose()

Tags: c#, enumeration, enumerator, yield-return

I'm using `yield return` to iterate over an `SqlDataReader`'s records:

```
IEnumerable<Reading> GetReadings() {
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(_query, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    yield return new Reading
                    {
                        End = reader.GetDateTime(0),
                        Value = reader.GetDouble(1)
                    };
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm then using an adapted version of [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976823/how-to-zip-or-rotate-a-variable-number-of-lists) to "zip" many iterators together:

```
   var enumerators = data.Select(d => new
   {
       d.Key,
       Enumerator = d.Value.GetEnumerator()
   }).ToList();

   while (true)
   {
       foreach (var item in enumerators)
       {
           if (!item.Enumerator.MoveNext())
           {
               yield break;
           }

           /*snip*/
       }

      /*snip*/
   }
```

In the method above, the enumerator's `Dispose()` is not explicitly called, and because they are not used within a `using` or `foreach` statement, would the underlying iterator remain in an open state?  In my case with an open `SqlConnection`.

Should I be calling `Dispose()` on the enumerators to make sure the whole downstream chain is closed?

Comment: Why would you not use the `using` syntax? It gets called automatically when the block context ends, which includes `yield` and `return`.

Comment: Having a variable number of enumerators in the zipmany style method makes it difficult to wrap each with `using`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> When enumerating over this iterator, if the enumerator's `Dispose()` is not explicitly called, and not used within a `using` statement, would the underlying iterator remain in an open state?

Let me re-phrase that question into a form that is easier to answer.

> When using `foreach` to enumerate via an iterator block that contains a `using` statement, are the resources disposed of when control leaves the loop?

Yes.

> What mechanisms ensure this?

These three:

- A `using` statement is just a convenient way to write a `try-finally` where the `finally` disposes of the resource.
- The `foreach` loop is *also* a convenient syntax for `try-finally`, and again, the `finally` calls `Dispose` on the enumerator when control leaves the loop.
- The enumerator produced by an iterator block implements `IDisposable`. Calling `Dispose()` on it ensures that all the `finally` blocks in the iterator block are executed, including `finally` blocks that come from `using` statements.

> If I avoid the `foreach` loop, call `GetEnumerator` myself, and don't call `Dispose` on the enumerator, do I have a guarantee that the `finally` blocks of the enumerator will run?

Nope.  **Always dispose your enumerators**. They implement `IDisposable` for a reason.

Is that now clear?

If this subject interests you then you should read my long series on design characteristics of iterator blocks in C#.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/iterators/

Comment: What about `item` which is `Enumerator` itself?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: An `IEnumerator<T>` implements `IDisposable`. If you have an `IDisposable` and you never call `Dispose()` then the disposal code doesn't run.

Comment: Yes, it is obviously. My comment depend on OP question and I see misleading between question and answer.

Answer (score 0):

You call `Dispose` to deallocate *resources* allocated by the connection and call `Close` to just close the connection. After`Close` call the connection may be pushed in connection pool, if runtime that found suitable, in case of `Dispose`, instead, it will be scheduled for destroy .

So all depends on what you mean saying "valid" state.

If it's enclosed in `using`dirrective, which is nothing else then `try/finally`, you have a guarantee that even if any exception happen in iteration the connection will be closed *and* its resources will be destroyed. In other cases you have to handle all it by yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Just to add some nuance to this:

Array-enumerators are NOT generic and are not disposable

Collection-enumerators ARE generic of  and are disposable but only if T itself is a reference-type ... not a value-type

So if you use GetEnumerator(), be sure to use

```
IEnumerator arrayEnumerator = arrayToEnumerate.GetEnumerator();
IEnumerator<T> collectionEnumerator = collectionToEnumerate.GetEnumerator();
```

then later in your code

```
collectionEnumerator.Dispose(); // compiles if T is reference-type but NOT value-type
```

Examples:

```
object[] theObjectArray = [...]
IEnumerator arrayEnumerator = theObjectArray.GetEnumerator(); // does not return 
IEnumerator<object> and is not disposable
arrayEnumerator.Dispose(); // won't compile

List<double> theListOfDoubles = [...]
IEnumerator<someObject> doubleEnumerator = doubleEnumerator.GetEnumerator();
doubleEnumerator.Dispose(); // won't compile

List<someObject> theListOfObjects = [...]
IEnumerator<someObject> objectEnumerator = theListOfObjects.GetEnumerator(); // disposable
objectEnumerator.Dispose(); // compiles & runs
```