# Recursive generator - manual zip vs operator

Tags: raku

Here's exercise 5.F.2 from 'A Book of Abstract Algebra' by Charles C Pinter:

> Let `G` be the group `{e, a, b, b^2, b^3, ab, ab^2, ab^3}` whose
>   generators satisfy `a^2 = e`, `b^4 = e`, `ba = ab^3`. Write the table
>   of `G`. (`G` is called the dihedral group D4.)

Here's a little Perl 6 program which presents a solution:

```
sub generate(%eqs, $s)
{
    my @results = ();

    for %eqs.kv -> $key, $val {
        if $s ~~ /$key/ { @results.push($s.subst(/$key/, $val)); }
        if $s ~~ /$val/ { @results.push($s.subst(/$val/, $key)); }
    }

    for @results -> $result { take $result; }

    my @arrs = @results.map({ gather generate(%eqs, $_) });

    my $i = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        for @arrs -> @arr { take @arr[$i]; }

        $i++;
    }
}

sub table(@G, %eqs)
{
    printf "     |";   for @G -> $y { printf "%-5s|", $y; }; say '';

    printf "-----|";   for @G -> $y { printf "-----|";    }; say '';

    for @G -> $x {

        printf "%-5s|", $x;

        for @G -> $y {
            my $result = (gather generate(%eqs, "$x$y")).first(* (elem) @G);

            printf "%-5s|", $result;
        }
    say ''
    }    
}

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Pinter 5.F.2

my @G = <e a b bb bbb ab abb abbb>;

my %eqs = <aa e   bbbb e   ba abbb>; %eqs<e> = '';

table @G, %eqs;
```

Here's what the resulting table looks like:

[image]

Let's focus on these particular lines from `generate`:

```
my @arrs = @results.map({ gather generate(%eqs, $_) });

my $i = 0;

while (1)
{
    for @arrs -> @arr { take @arr[$i]; }

    $i++;
}
```

A recursive call to `generate` is made for each of the items in `@results`. Then we're effectively performing a manual 'zip' on the resulting sequences. However, Perl 6 has `zip` and the `Z` operator.

Instead of the above lines, I'd like to do something like this:

```
for ([Z] @results.map({ gather generate(%eqs, $_) })).flat -> $elt { take $elt; }
```

So here's the full `generate` using `Z`:

```
sub generate(%eqs, $s)
{
    my @results = ();

    for %eqs.kv -> $key, $val {
        if $s ~~ /$key/ { @results.push($s.subst(/$key/, $val)); }
        if $s ~~ /$val/ { @results.push($s.subst(/$val/, $key)); }
    }

    for @results -> $result { take $result; }

    for ([Z] @results.map({ gather generate(%eqs, $_) })).flat -> $elt { take $elt; }
}
```

The issue with the `Z` version of generate is that it hangs...

[image]

So, my question is, is there a way to write `generate` in terms of `Z`?

Besides this core question, feel free to share alternative solutions to the exercise which explore and showcase Perl 6.

---

As another example, here's exercise 5.F.3 from the same book:

> Let G be the group `{e, a, b, b^2, b^3, ab, ab^2, ab^3}` whose
>   generators satisfy `a^4 = e`, `a^2 = b^2`, `ba = ab^3`. Write the
>   table of `G`. (G is called the quaternion group.)

And the program above displaying the table:

[image]

---

As an aside, this program was converted from a version in C#. Here's how `generate` looks there using LINQ and a version of [ZipMany](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17977375/268581) courtesy of [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert).

```
    static IEnumerable<string> generate(Dictionary<string,string> eqs, string s)
    {
        var results = new List<string>();

        foreach (var elt in eqs)
        {
            if (new Regex(elt.Key).IsMatch(s))
                results.Add(new Regex(elt.Key).Replace(s, elt.Value, 1));

            if (new Regex(elt.Value).IsMatch(s))
                results.Add(new Regex(elt.Value).Replace(s, elt.Key, 1));
        }

        foreach (var result in results) yield return result;

        foreach (var elt in ZipMany(results.Select(elt => generate(eqs, elt)), elts => elts).SelectMany(elts => elts))
            yield return elt;
    }
```

The entire C# program: [link](https://gist.github.com/dharmatech/06e15574632325361b531749eac44ba8).

Comment: The above Perl 6 example as a [Jupyter notebook](https://github.com/bduggan/p6-jupyter-kernel/blob/master/eg/pinter-5.F.ipynb).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Why your use of `zip` doesn't work

Your code assumes that `[Z]` ("reducing with the zip operator") can be used to get the [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) of a list-of-lists.

Unfortunately, this **doesn't work** in the general case.
It 'usually' works, but breaks on one edge case: Namely, when the list-of-lists is a list of exactly *one* list. Observe:

```perl6
my @a = <a b c>, <1 2 3>, <X Y Z>; put [Z~] @a;  # a1X b2Y c3Z
my @b = <a b c>, <1 2 3>;          put [Z~] @b;  # a1 b2 c3
my @c = <a b c>,;                  put [Z~] @c;  # abc
my @d;                             put [Z~] @d;  #
```

In the first two examples (3 and 2 sub-lists), you can see that the transpose of `@a` was returned just fine. The fourth example (0 sub-lists) does the right thing as well.

But the third example (1 sub-list) didn't print `a b c` as one would expect, i.e. it didn't return the transpose of `@a` in that case, but rather (it seems) the transpose of `@a[0]`.

Sadly, this is not a Rakudo bug (in which case it could simply be fixed), but an unforseen interaction of two Perl 6 design decisions, namely:

- The **reduce meta-operator `[ ]`** handles an input list with a single element by calling the operator it's applied to with one argument (said element).
  In case you're wondering, an infix operator can be called with only one argument by invoking its function object:  `&infix:<Z>( <a b c>, )`.
- The **zip operator `Z` and function `zip`** (like other built-ins that accept nested lists), follows the so-called "single-argument rule" – i.e. its signature uses a [single-argument slurpy parameter](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Signature#Single_Argument_Rule_Slurpy). This means that when it is called with a single argument, it will descend into it and consider its *elements* the actual arguments to use. (See also [Slurpy conventions](https://docs.perl6.org/language/functions#Slurpy_Conventions).)
  So `zip(<a b c>,)` is treated as `zip("a", "b", "c")`.

Both features provide some nice convenience in many other cases, but in this case their interaction regrettably poses a trap.

#### How to make it work with `zip`

You could check the number of elements of `@arrs`, and special-case the "exactly 1 sub-list" case:

```perl6
my @arrs = @results.map({ gather generate(%eqs, $_) });

if @arrs.elems == 1 {
    .take for @arrs[0][];
}
else {
    .take for flat [Z] @arrs
}
```

The `[]` is a "[zen slice](https://docs.perl6.org/language/subscripts.html#Zen_slices)" - it returns the list unchanged, but without the item container that the parent Array wrapped it in. This is needed because the `for` loop would consider anything wrapped in an item container as a single item and only do one iteration.

Of course, this if-else solution is not very elegant, which probably negates your reason for trying to use `zip` in the first place.

#### How to write the code more elegantly *without* `zip`

Refer to [Christoph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44829599/1160124).

Comment: Great explanation of `zip`. Thanks smls!

Comment: I updated the question to include exercise 3 from the same text. The general approach demonstrated in the question solves that exercise as well.

Comment: PS: You're not the first to mistakenly assume that `[Z]` can be used to get the transpose of a list of arbitrary size. I've run afoul of that in the past, and have seen it in other people's Perl 6 code as well. It's a real trap, and should probably be mentioned [here](https://docs.perl6.org/language/traps).

Comment: I've added an answer which includes your approach.

Answer (score 6):

It might be possible with a `Z`, but for my poor little brain, zipping recursively generated lazy lists is too much.

Instead, I did some other simplifications:

```
sub generate($s, %eqs) {
    take $s;

    # the given equations normalize the string, ie there's no need to apply
    # the inverse relation
    for %eqs.kv -> $k, $v {
        # make copy of $s so we can use s/// instead of .subst
        my $t = $s;
        generate $t, %eqs
            if $t ~~ s/$k/$v/;
    }
}

sub table(@G, %eqs) {
    # compute the set only once instead of implicitly on each call to (elem)
    my $G = set @G;

    # some code golfing
    put ['', |@G]>>.fmt('%-5s|').join;
    put '-----|' x @G + 1;

    for @G -> $x {
        printf '%-5s|', $x;

        for @G -> $y {
            printf '%-5s|', (gather generate("$x$y", %eqs)).first(* (elem) $G);
        }

        put '';
    }    
}

my @G = <e a b bb bbb ab abb abbb>;

# use double brackets so we can have empty strings
my %eqs = <<aa e   bbbb e   ba abbb   e ''>>;

table @G, %eqs;
```

---

Here is a compact rewrite of `generate` that does bidirectional substitution, still without an explicit zip:

```
sub generate($s, %eqs) {
    my @results = do for |%eqs.pairs, |%eqs.antipairs -> (:$key, :$value) {
        take $s.subst($key, $value) if $s ~~ /$key/;
    }

    my @seqs = @results.map: { gather generate($_, %eqs) }
    for 0..* -> $i { take .[$i] for @seqs }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Christoph! You're right; exercise 2 only requires replacing 'a -> b' given 'a == b'. It does not require 'b -> a'. I've added exercise 3 to the original question as an example of one where using the equations in both directions is required.

Comment: I like the use of double brackets and the golfed version of the table generation!

Comment: I believe exercise 3 was why I originally went down the recursive generator route.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a version of `generate` that uses the approach demonstrated by [smls](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1160124/smls):

```
sub generate(%eqs, $s)
{
    my @results = ();

    for %eqs.kv -> $key, $val {
        if $s ~~ /$key/ { @results.push($s.subst(/$key/, $val)); }
        if $s ~~ /$val/ { @results.push($s.subst(/$val/, $key)); }
    }

    for @results -> $result { take $result; }

    my @arrs = @results.map({ gather generate(%eqs, $_) });

    if @arrs.elems == 1 { .take for @arrs[0][]; }
    else { .take for flat [Z] @arrs; }
}
```

I've tested it and it works on exercises 2 and 3.

As [smls](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1160124/smls) mentions in his answer, `zip` doesn't do what we were expecting when the given array of arrays only contains a single array. So, let's make a version of `zip` which *does* work with one or more arrays:

```
sub zip-many (@arrs)
{
    if @arrs.elems == 1 { .take for @arrs[0][];     }
    else                { .take for flat [Z] @arrs; }
}
```

And now, `generate` in terms of `zip-many`:

```
sub generate(%eqs, $s)
{
    my @results = ();

    for %eqs.kv -> $key, $val {
        if $s ~~ /$key/ { @results.push($s.subst(/$key/, $val)); }
        if $s ~~ /$val/ { @results.push($s.subst(/$val/, $key)); }
    }

    for @results -> $result { take $result; }

    zip-many @results.map({ gather generate(%eqs, $_) });
}
```

That looks pretty good.

Thanks [smls](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1160124/smls)!

---

[smls](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1160124/smls) suggests in a comment below that `zip-many` not invoke `take`, leaving that to `generate`. Let's also move `flat` from `zip-many` to `generate`.

The slimmed down `zip-many`:

```
sub zip-many (@arrs) { @arrs == 1 ?? @arrs[0][] !! [Z] @arrs }
```

And the `generate` to go along with it:

```
sub generate(%eqs, $s)
{
    my @results;

    for %eqs.kv -> $key, $val {
        if $s ~~ /$key/ { @results.push($s.subst(/$key/, $val)); }
        if $s ~~ /$val/ { @results.push($s.subst(/$val/, $key)); }
    }

    .take for @results;

    .take for flat zip-many @results.map({ gather generate(%eqs, $_) });
}
```

Comment: Doing the `take` step inside the `zip-many` function, could be considered action-at-a-distance which makes the code harder to follow. I'd probably slim it down to `sub zip-many (+@arrays) { flat @arrays == 1 ?? @arrays[0][] !! [Z] @arrays }` and then do `.take for zip-many @results.map({...`.

Comment: @smls Good suggestion. I've updated the answer to incorporate this approach.

Comment: two more comments: the initialization of `@results` is unnecessary, and `for @results -> $result { take $result; }` can be written as `.take for @results` or not-quite-but-almost-equivalently as `take slip @results`

Comment: @Christoph good suggestions! I've updated the answer to incorporate them.

Answer (score 0):

Testing the keys and values separately seems a bit silly; your strings aren't really regexes, so there's no need for `//` anywhere in your code.

```
sub generate($s, @eqs) {
    my @results = do for @eqs.kv -> $i, $equation {
        take $s.subst($equation, @eqs[ $i +^ 1 ]) if $s.index: $equation
    }

    my @seqs = @results.map: { gather generate($_, @eqs) }
    for 0..* -> $i { take .[$i] for @seqs }
}
```

Obviously with this version of `generate` you'll have to rewrite `table` to use `@eqs` instead of `%eqs`.